# C program dealing with arithmetic giving error: called object not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I keep getting error for my program and I would really appreciate it if someone can help.

Here is the code:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {

  int x; 

  float y;    

  for ( x = 1; x < 21; x++) {
      y = (3(x * x) - x) / 18;
      printf("%d %10f\n", x, y);   
  }   
  return 0; 
}
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
question2.c: In function ‘main’: 
question2.c:13:13: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
   y = (3(x * x) - x) / 18;
```

Comment: look at this again. `y = (3(x * x) - x) / 18;`.Maybe missing something

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*

Comment: It's important to understand what the error message is pointing to. `question2.c:13:13` is telling you that the compiler thinks that the error is on line 13 of your program starting at the 13th character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3(x*x)` should be `3*(x*x)` or just `(3*x*x)`.

The way you've written it, it looks like you are calling a function named `3`, which is not a `function or function pointer`; hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Add "*" in multiplication

```
for ( x = 1; x < 21; x++) {
      y = (3*(x * x) - x) / 18;
      printf("%d %10f\n", x, y);   
  }
```